# Updating brushed points in plot in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, interactive, brush

Possibly similar to [Update brush points in an Image in Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038855/update-brush-points-in-an-image-in-shiny-app)

I have a Shiny app that allows users to interactively annotate regions that correspond to events on a time-series plot that are always consecutive in the x-space. However, the duration of events varies, such that the user is required to brush the points corresponding to the event. Each time the user brushes the points they are required to mark the event as such, and then move on to marking the next event (i.e. brushing its points).

In the following example, I have almost all I need, (forgive the error messages at first). Below, the user can brush some points on the plot, mark the event (which nudges the selection of brushed points to the right in x space) so that the subsequently brushed points begin where the previous event began. Try it to see that the values in the brush actually change.

My challenge is now that I need the selection window in the plot (the thing that generates the brush) to move correspondingly as well, such that the user can always just do one click to move the right hand side event on the plot to delimit the event.

If the selected window is not changeable, I believe I can redefine the subset of the data stored in the reactive values of ´values$mtcarz´ because using brushOpts(clip=TRUE) should clip the selected window to the dataframe. This way, the user would have to only open the window from the left side of the plot each time the mark the event. But I would rather not have to do that. Is there a way to redraw the plot each time I mark the event?

Points awarded for nudging the selected window and showing it on the plot.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(
plotOutput(
  outputId = "plot",
  brush = brushOpts(
    id = "plotBrush",
    delay = 5000, direction = "x"
  )
),

actionButton("move_brush_to_edge", "Mark event and scootch selected points to right by selected x-range"),
verbatimTextOutput("brushed_points"),
verbatimTextOutput("thebrush")

),
server = function(input, output, session) {

values<-reactiveValues()
values$mtcarz<-reactive({mtcars})
observeEvent(input$plotBrush,{
  values$thebrush<-reactive({input$plotBrush})
})


output$plot <- renderPlot({

  ggplot(values$mtcarz(), aes(wt, mpg)) +
    geom_point()
  })


bpts<-reactive({
   values$thebrush
  })
output$brushed_points<-renderPrint({
  brushedPoints(values$mtcarz(),  values$thebrush())
  })
output$thebrush<-renderPrint({
   values$thebrush()
})

observeEvent(input$move_brush_to_edge, {
  mtbrushed<-      brushedPoints(values$mtcarz(),  values$thebrush())
  thebrushintime<-values$thebrush()
  scoot<-thebrushintime$xmax-thebrushintime$xmin
  thebrushintime$xmin<-thebrushintime$xmin+scoot
  thebrushintime$xmax<-thebrushintime$xmax+scoot
  values$thebrush<-reactive({thebrushintime})
})
}
)
```

Comment: After brushing, did you know that you can hover your mouse on the rectangle and then move the rectangle or widen it.

Comment: Yes I do. Currently the user is forced to hover the mouse on the rectangle and then move *both* x borders of the rectangle. My goal here is to make the user move *only* the right-hand-side border (if at all), because the left-hand-side border of the next event to select will always be the previous selections´s right-hand-side border (because events are supposed to be always subsequent with no x space intervening). As far as the events go, subsequent event duration in x space are pretty well correlated, so using the previous event´s duration is a good start for the user.